# How to read my application screen pixel data with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot

I am trying to read my application screen pixel data in my Qt Qml application.

The first approach was `grabToImage()`, which is fast in my PC. But the same is taking seconds to grab image in my embedded device.

So I tried to read `/dev/fb0`, using `QFile::readAll`,

```
QFile file("/dev/fb0");
QFile dataFile("/home/icu/WorkSpace/Samples/FBRead/Exe/data.bin");

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << file.errorString();
}

if(!dataFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << dataFile.errorString();
}

QTextStream in(&file);

QString data;
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "start read";

//    while(!in.atEnd())
//    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "read";
        data = in.readAll();
//        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << data;
//    }

QByteArray dataBytes;
dataBytes.append(data);

dataFile.write(dataBytes);

file.close();
dataFile.close();
```

I tried to open the file with some tool which shows image reading from raw file. But it did not show any data. When I open the file data is like `01 01 01 00 01 01 01 00 ...`

Is there any alternate way to read my screen pixel data fast? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if using a `QTextStream` and converting data to `QString` and then back to `QByteArray` is the best way to do it. As explained [in Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8) constructing a `QString` from `QByteArray` forces a conversion to UTF-8 and also stops copying at the first null character, so you are modifying your pixel data and not getting it completely. Try copying data directly between files instead:

```
bool grabScreenToFile(const QString& outPath) {
  QFile inFile("/dev/fb0");
  QFile outFile(outPath);

  // ...

  outFile.write(inFile.readAll());

  return true;
}
```

To check if this is copying the actual content of the file and you have no problem with it (truncation, conversions, ...), compare with the file obtained using `cat /dev/fb0 > grab.raw` (note that it is not a JPEG or PNG image but a raw buffer).

---

**/dev/fb0**

[This link](http://www.cnx-software.com/2010/07/18/how-to-do-a-framebuffer-screenshot/) contains a long explanation about grabbing the framebuffer from the `/dev/fb0` device. Basically, it points out that you must pay attention to the depth of the buffer, since pixels may be packed in different ways.

---

On the other hand, have you tried any other of the grabbing methods provided by Qt, such as [`QScreen::grabWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow)? Maybe its performance is better that the QML's [`QQuickItem::grabToImage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#grabToImage) (which is the one I guess you are using). Indeed, the documentation states:

> This function will render the item to an offscreen surface and copy that surface from the GPU's memory into the CPU's memory, which can be quite costly.

Following code is a modification of the [screenshot example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html).

```
auto screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
if (const QWindow *window = windowHandle()) {
    screen = window->screen();
}
if (screen) {    
    const auto pixmap = screen->grabWindow(yourWidget->winId());
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried the file write method as you mentioned, but found no difference in the output file. I shall check the grabwindow now. :) thanks for the post.

Comment: Oh, well, hope the other one improves the performance at least... I've updated the answer to include a couple of options regarding the format of the framebuffer.

Comment: i've tried the second option, and seems fast in my pc, but when i run the same in embedded device `grabwindow()` returns null. My code is `QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap();
    QTime timer;
    timer.start();
    pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "time elapsed" << timer.elapsed() << "ms";
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "pixmap is null" << pixmap.isNull();
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "saved is" << pixmap.save("/opt/img.png");
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";`

Comment: When i run in eglfs i gets the comment _grabWindow: Not supported for non-composited OpenGL content. Use QQuickWindow::grabWindow() instead._ . so looking into it... :(